# VB Loading a list of variables from a text document

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently trying to load a list of variables that are formatted like this:

```
5,
6,
3,
3,
```

etc, and I'm trying to output them to variables like this:

```
Strength = variablesList(1)
Agility = variablesList(2)
```

But so far, I've not been able to find a solution that seems to work for what I'm trying to do.

I'm currently working with:

```
Dim destination As String = Environment.GetFolderPath("C:\Roll20Output\Class" + outputClass + "2.txt")
        Dim FileReader1 As New StreamReader(destination)
        Dim Contents1 As String
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        While FileReader1.Peek <> -1
            Contents1 = FileReader1.ReadLine
            Dim array As New ArrayList
            array.AddRange(Contents1.Split(","))
            variablesList.Add(array)
        End While

        Strength = variablesList(1)
        Agility = variablesList(2)
```

But so far I can't seem to get anything to output.

Would anyone be able to help?

Thanks

Comment: Go to your project properties and set Option Strict to ON. What happens then?

Comment: Why is there a `,` at the end of each line? In other words: Are the values separated by `,` or by line breaks?

Comment: @Steve
Error 8 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'Integer'. ..\Roll20\Roll20\Form1.vb

Comment: @Heinzi
I don't really need the , but this is the way I found someone else using it, so I just went with it. I can switch to new lines if needs be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a lot of outdated stuff in your code (reading a file with StreamReader, ArrayList instead of `List<T>`, etc.). I would suggest the following (untested):

```
' Returns an array with one string per line
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\...\SomeFile.txt")

' Remove trailing `,` - LINQ magic
lines = (From s In lines Select s.TrimEnd(","c)).ToArray()

Dim strength = CInt(lines(0))
Dim agility = CInt(lines(1))
...
```

If you get rid of the useless trailing commas, you can skip the second step. If you use *only* commas instead of new lines, the first step becomes:

```
Dim lines = File.ReadAllText("C:\...\SomeFile.txt").Split(","c)
```

Comment: Just gave this a try, I don't seem to get anything as an output for some reason (I tried linking it to a label to see if it was doing anything)

Comment: @Zarconite: Then use the debugger to step though it line by line and check where the variable values differ from your expected values.

Comment: Just managed to get it working, I removed all the comas from the list and changed the file path and it seems to be working, Thanks!